# How to add dynamic url in self registration welcome email experience cloud

Tags: apex, url, experience-cloud, guest-user, self-registration

I currently have website from were users get authenticated by the IDP in Salesforce and logged into the customer site. Currently with a return url parameter I can redirect the user to the page where they started the login.

I want to be able to do this also for the self registration. The link in the welcome email should dynamically redirect the user to the page where the self-registration was started since these could be different with some parameters of the customer (new)id account in example.

I currently found that I can customize the CommunitiesSelfRegController apex class but do not know how the URL is generated in the welcome email. Is it possible to create a dynamic url for the welcome email or do I need to setup a selfregistrastion flow to achieve this or is this not even possible. I could not find any documentation or example how to achieve this. What I am looking for is some steps where to look for and how to achive this if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I was able to resolve this by adding a flow with an extra field on the login page which gets saved on the user and hide the field with CSS and passing the URL to this hidden field. I created a lightning component which on pageload uses the saved url and does a goto url.